# Python: conditional group by in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How can you perform a conditional group by operation in a dataframe in the sense that you only group those elements fulfilling a certain condition and leave the other elements untouched?

Suppose I have the below dataframe:

[initial dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcJ0j.png)

How can I only group the elements with type "type 2" and set the new name "z"

[resulting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlRN8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset the data (by 'Type' here), group the required subset and union them back.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'value': [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1]})
df1 = df[df['type']==1]
df2 = df[df['type']==2]

df2_grouped = df2.groupby('type').mean().reset_index(False)

df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2_grouped])
df_final

  type  value
0   1   2
1   1   3
2   1   4
3   1   1
0   2   2
```

Comment: why do we need to set `reset_index(False)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you talk about pandas dataframe, the following solution should do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'value': [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1]})
df_2 = df[df['type'] == 2]
```

In your example:

```
z= df[df['type'] == 'type 2']
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input. I was indeed refering to a dataframe. In the solution you are proposing you create a subsample out of the dataframe. What I'm looking for is a 'group by' operation, meaning that the subsample is grouped into one line and the values are summed up. The elements of the initial dataframe that don't respect the filter/ should be in the resulting dataframe as well. See the 2 illustrations attached in the original message. All type 2 elements are grouped into one row (values are summed up)

Comment: Hi. Misunderstood your question. If you want the group by sum, you can do that very simple actually; df.groupby('type').sum()